# Which types of Affinity Chart rewards can't be cleared with Merc Missions?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Most blade affinity chart rewards can be earned either by meeting their condition or by sending the blade out on Merc Missions. However, I've noticed that some rewards seem to stay uncleared no matter Merc Missions a blade goes on. (Crosette's Ardent Cooking, several of Boreas's abilities, and all of Zenobia's level 2 abilities)

Are there certain types of Affinity Chart rewards that can't be cleared through Merc Missions?

[image: Boreas's uncleared affinity chart nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a post by TechnomagusPrime](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/7mgxgn/psa_merc_missions_affinity_charts_and_you/), Merc Missions will not contribute towards completing nodes with the following conditions:

> - Deal X damage in a single attack
> - Heal X damage
> - Defeat <Named Unique Monster> in <location>
> - View Heart-to-Heart
> - Complete <Named> Mission (Refers to Rare Blade unique Side Quests, not Merc Missions)
> - Use <Unique Skill> to create items
> - Head to <Location> on <Titan>

Note that this list is incomplete. I've observed that the following abilities on rare blades are also uncompletable with Merc Missions.

- Use <pouch item> (Boreas, but only some of the nodes)
- Make fabric (Vale)
- Overkill a monster in a Chain Attack. (Poppibuster)
- Complete Stage <x> in Tiger! Tiger!. (Poppibuster)